# How to ensure accept header application/*+json will also trigger JsonView in CakePHP 2.x?

Tags: json, cakephp, http-headers, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

I am building an API server out of CakePHP.

I am building it according to the following requirements:

- not using `.json` in the url to trigger the `JsonView`
- not using `v1` in the url to do versioning
- using accept headers `application/Person.1.0+json` to do versioning and trigger `JsonView`

I understand that CakePHP already is looking out for `application/json` in the accept header [to trigger the JsonView](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html).

How do I extend the framework so that it can also trigger JsonView as well?

Please be mindful that the accept header is in the form of `application/ModelName.version+json`

Comment: Why fighting the framework when you got the solution already at end to easily output Json data? For me a good API is clear and straightforward, which in this case means, it expects the extension json for Json in- and output. See how other major APIs do it.

Comment: @mark GitHub also has a weird accept header for their api. See http://developer.github.com/v3/ They use `Accept: application/vnd.github.beta+json`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `CakeResponse::type()` to map your custom accept header to type 'json'. Though depending on your app size it would mean adding lot of headers if you plan to use one accept header per model like `application/ModelName.version+json`.

Comment: How about adding multiple accept headers? 

application/json;application/MOdelName.version+json. 

Would CakePHP automatically detect this and render JsonView?

of course the task of finding out which ModelName and version is up to my code to figure out via $this->request in the controller, I suppose.

Comment: Or do you suggest I simply use 1 custom header for each version of the api? meaning like this: `Accept: application/appname.version+json`

Comment: I personally feel one header per model is a bit excessive and would suggest just using one per api version.

Comment: I can go along with that. So your answer would work with that?